# Access VBA get Function to pass data to Sub for its Cancel property

Tags: function, ms-access, vba

I have a number of dates on a form and started out validating them each individually. Wanted to replace all these checks with one function which could be called from each of their 'before update' events. Problem is that I can't get the focus to remain on the control when validation fails.

```
Public Function CheckDate(datefield As TextBox) As Integer

Dim this_date As Date
Dim DOB As Date
Dim first_seen As Date
this_date = Conversion.CDate(datefield.text)
DOB = [Forms]![generic]![date_of_birth]
first_seen = [Forms]![generic]![date_first_seen]

If Not IsNull(this_date) Then
    'date of birth must precede any other date
    If this_date < DOB Then
        MsgBox "This date precedes the date of birth", vbExclamation, "Invalid date"
        CheckDate = -1
        Exit Function
    End If
    'date can't be in the future
    If this_date > DateTime.Date Then
        MsgBox "This date is in the future", vbExclamation, "Invalid date"
        CheckDate = -1
        Exit Function
    End If
    'all investigation/treatment dates must be >= date first seen
    If Not IsNull(first_seen) Then
        If this_date < first_seen Then
            MsgBox "This date precedes the date patient was first seen", vbExclamation, "Invalid date"
            CheckDate = -1
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If
End If

End Function
```

Within

```
Private Sub xray_date_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
```

I've tried:

```
Call CheckDate(xray_date)
```

which displays correct message but moves focus from control instead of keeping it there for editing.

```
Cancel = CheckDate(xray_date)
```

doesn't appear to do anything, allowing invalid data to be passed for storage. So what way should I be calling the function in order to have the BeforeUpdate's Cancel event set to True when validation fails?

Comment: @Hansup doesn't the function's signature `CheckDate(datefield As TextBox)` make it impossible to pass anything other than a TextBox?

Comment: @HansUp Well I missed that `Cancel = CheckDate(xray_date)` 
doesn't appear to do anything while `Call CheckDate(xray_date)` does,  which shouldn't be the case, maybe you are on to something there.

Comment: I think you just should not check those dates at control level, but rather using the BefereUpdate event of the form. There you have a Cancel option, plus you don't bother the user until he tries to save it all. Don't forget that you do NOT control the order in which the user fills the controls ! HE is the master of the mouse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I struggled to understand your sample code, so I built a table with Date/Time fields: date_of_birth; date_first_seen; and xray_date.  Then built a form based on that table with these text boxes bound to those fields: txtDate_of_birth; txtDate_first_seen; and txtXray_date.

This is my form's code module, and AFAICT it validates `txtXray_date` as you want.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Function CheckDate(ctlDate As TextBox) As Integer
    Const clngChecks As Long = 3 ' change this to match the number
                                 ' of conditions in the For loop
    Const cstrTitle As String = "Invalid date"
    Dim i As Long
    Dim intReturn As Integer
    Dim lngButtons As Long
    Dim strPrompt As String
    Dim strTitle As String

    lngButtons = vbExclamation
    strPrompt = vbNullString ' make it explicit
    intReturn = 0 ' make it explicit

    For i = 1 To clngChecks
        Select Case i
        Case 1
            'date of birth must precede any other date
            If ctlDate < Me.txtDate_of_birth Then
                strPrompt = "This date precedes the date of birth"
                Exit For
            End If
        Case 2
            'date can't be in the future
            If ctlDate > DateTime.Date Then
                strPrompt = "This date is in the future"
                Exit For
            End If
        Case 3
            'all investigation/treatment dates must be >= date first seen
            If ctlDate < Me.txtDate_first_seen Then
                strPrompt = "This date precedes the date patient was first seen"
                Exit For
            End If
        End Select
    Next i

    If Len(strPrompt) > 0 Then
        MsgBox strPrompt, lngButtons, cstrTitle
        intReturn = -1
    End If
    CheckDate = intReturn
End Function

Private Sub txtXray_date_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    Cancel = CheckDate(Me.txtXray_date)
End Sub
```

Comment: I came to the same conclusion. Maybe if the OP did a debug->compile it might shed some light.

Comment: @HansUp: I've replaced my function with yours, but still having difficulties. Firstly I got a message on invalid use of the Me keyword, so I took it out, but then txtDate_of_birth wasn't defined, so I changed it to [Forms]![form]![txtDate_of_birth]. However it then works exactly as my function did in that it displayed the message box but then control moved from the date being checked onto the next control on the form and the invalid date was saved to the table. Sorry that my original code seems to be confusing, new to using VBA.

Comment: The error about invalid use of the `Me` keyword suggests you stored that code in some other module instead of the the form's code module.  I can't think of any other reason why `Me` would be invalid.

Comment: @HansUp: Moved it from the separate module where I have all the functions into the main one and although it accepts Me, the same problem remains - message box presented but focus moves to next control and invalid data is stored

Comment: Run *Debug->Compile* from the VB editor's main menu as Conrad suggested.   This suggestion assumes you have included `Option Explicit` in the Declarations section of your form's module; add it if it's not there.  Fix anything the compiler complains about.  If that effort doesn't resolve everything, upload a copy of your database somewhere we can get it and give us a link to it.

Comment: Option Explicit already included, and Debug->Compile doesn't find any problems. Will see if I can upload copy as you suggest. Very frustrating!

Comment: Worked out what the problem was - as simple as swapping vbExclamation for vbOKOnly!  HansUp, thank you for your help, the bones of your function are proving very useful elsewhere in my code as well. On to my next problem now ...